# Permission problems when adding a image with google slides API

Tags: google-api

I am trying to add an image to a slide using the Google Slides API.

My request to

```
https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/1nuZwR325hRmmgzyZNMZ0r6bUFanrREWD-t5sF2pGYeo::batchUpdate
```

has this payload:

```
{
  "requests" => [
    {
      "createImage" => {
        "elementProperties" => {
          "pageObjectId" => "SLIDES_API2078288406_0"
        },
        "url" => "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Meo1eMAUHV59DNzwjwU_SX4BFds7HZID&export=download"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but fails with the following response:

```
{
  "error" => {
    "code" => 400,
    "message" => "Invalid requests[0].createImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden.",
    "status" => "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

even though checking the file permissions returns this response:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#permissionList",
 "permissions": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "id": "anyoneWithLink",
   "type": "anyone",
   "role": "reader",
   "allowFileDiscovery": false
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "id": "14156222269725841761",
   "type": "user",
   "role": "owner"
  }
 ]
}
```

and

- inserting the same image manually via `insert -> image -> by URL` works perfectly
- and downloading the image wit curl works fine too

Although I use [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) to do this, it seems (to me) like a language-agnostic problem (hence the absence of a "perl" tag). Anyway, code below, just in case:

```
helper 'google_add_image_to_slide_p' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    my $img_id   = shift;
    my $pres_id = shift;
    my $page_id = shift;

    $c->log->info("adding image $img_id to page $page_id");

    my $update = {
              requests => [
                       {
                        "createImage" =>
                           {
                               elementProperties => { pageObjectId => $page_id },
                               url => "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Meo1eMAUHV59DNzwjwU_SX4BFds7HZID&export=download",
                           }
                       }
                  ]
         };
    $c->app->ua->post_p('https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/' . $pres_id . ':batchUpdate', json => $update);
};
```

So the question is: why am I getting an invalid request response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Meo1eMAUHV59DNzwjwU_SX4BFds7HZID&export=download

appears to be a weblinkdowload link from a google drive file.   In order for you to access this you must have access to the file itself.  You cant just send this link the api wont have access to read it.

Upload the file to some where that does not contain permissions attached to it.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that the file indeed does not have permissions attached - as tested by downloading from a different browser, without a google login, and with curl

Comment: The solution is to not use google drive webdownload link and google drive. You should place the file on a web server some where without an permissions.   You cant use webdownload link or google drive in this manner.